# RAM distribution of four slot Motherboard

Tags: desktop, memory

I have a Gigabyte Z790 Aorus Elite AX motherboard with single 16 GB Kingston Fury Beast DDR5 6000MHz C36 RAM installed. I bought a 32 GB kit (2 X 16GB) of G.Skill dual channel DDR5 6000MHz C36 RAM. Can I use all three sticks in the following distribution:

1. SLOT A: G.Skill DDR5 6000MHz C36 - 16GB
2. SLOT B: Kingston Fury Beast DDR5 6000MHz C36 - 16GB
3. SLOT C: G.Skill DDR5 6000MHz C36 - 16GB

Is there any performance issue with this configuration? Do I get a full 48GB Performance with these three RAMs?

I plan next month to add another 16 GB stick of Kingston Fury RAM in the 4th slot.

So the distribution will be:

1. SLOT A: G.Skill DDR5 6000MHz C36 - 16GB
2. SLOT B: Kingston Fury Beast DDR5 6000MHz C36 - 16GB
3. SLOT C: G.Skill DDR5 6000MHz C36 - 16GB
4. SLOT D: Kingston Fury Beast DDR5 6000MHz C36 - 16GB

Again I want to know as previously, is there any performance issue with this configuration? Do I get full 64GB performance?

Comment: I can't speak for your situation,. but mixing RAM manufacturers and CAS latency never ends well in my experience. Also, we can't answer your question without knowing exactly what motherboard you have. And this question doesn't belong on SO.

Comment: @Dai I have posted the same in Hardware Recommendation Beta. But didn't get my answer. I am using Gigabyte z790 Elite Ax motherboard. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Motherboard Manual

Gigabyte Z790 Aorus Elite AX Motherboard
[English Manual](https://download.gigabyte.com/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_z790-ae-series_e_221118.pdf?v=672a72e0a0eed6a8be6ff24ef4d196fb)   |   [Other Languages](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/Z790-AORUS-ELITE-AX-rev-11/support#support-manual)

Page 16 of the manual (section 2-4) is titled: **Installing the Memory**

> *Make sure that the motherboard supports the memory. It is recommended that memory of the same
> capacity, brand, speed, and chips be used. (Go to GIGABYTE's website for the latest supported
> memory speeds and memory modules.)*

They do not recommend mixing.  Also, have you visited the website as recommended?

> *Enabling Dual Channel memory mode will double the original memory bandwidth.*

In other words, a single stick, will not operate in dual-channel mode.  There is no indication that 3 sticks is a supported configuration, but you can always test it.

On the same page of the manual, they indicate how to arrange memory.

<sub>**page 16 of manual**</sub>
[image]

Comment: Thanks, your English Manual link became Chinese...

Comment: [Link now corrected](https://download.gigabyte.com/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_z790-ae-series_e_221118.pdf?v=672a72e0a0eed6a8be6ff24ef4d196fb "download English manual") .  Ty for catching that

Answer (score 1):

With 4-slot motherboards, follow these rules, top to bottom:

- Ideally use 2 or 4 identical modules, or at least 2 pairs of identical modules. Mixing increases chances of incompatibility. (Nb. the same mix can work can work better or worse in different motherboards.)
- If you aren't populating all the slots, leave every other slot empty and prefer slots farther from the CPU socket.
- With odd number of socket the overall performance may be worse, especially if you're using onboard graphics - run your own benchmarks.

Pairs are preferred because the memory controller can then run them in dual channel mode, which increases the bandwidth. Intel systems can use dual channel when 3 modules are in use, while AMD systems can't (AFAIK).

Farther slots are better because at the operating frequencies of RAM the signal can "bounce" from the unused ends of traces, causing interference. The problem is less pronounced when slots with longer traces are populated.

Answer (score 1):

**As for adding a third RAM if you already have one:**

It depends on what kind of task you want to run. For memory space extensive operations, adding a third stick will be superior. If you have dozens of tabs in your web browser, large CAD projects, or similar things, this configuration may be more comfortable for your daily work.

On the other hand, adding a third stick will degrade the bandwidth to a single channel, which may cripple performance. Its hard to say how much exactly, but generally games will lose only 1-2% FPS but get a few more short fps drops and computational tasks will slow down by 5-10% compared to two sticks (usually, may be more in some uncommon tasks). If you want to get full performance and do not have problems with insufficient memory already, your setup will actually get worse with additional memory.

**As for four sticks from other manufacturers:**

This configuration should generally be safe, since you have memory with the same clock and latency. But it's generally not recommended to mix different memory sticks because you can't be sure without testing.

- If three stick config works without problems (run Memtest), four stick config should work too. If not, adding more sticks won't change that.
- Even if three sticks works, there is still a risk that four sticks will not pair in quad channel.

You should definitely do extensive memory tests when mixing sticks. Any difference between the sticks increases the risk of memory errors. Check it before you lose data due to some random bluescreen.

**Conclusion:**

The best option would be to sell your old stick and buy a new set to match existing 32GB. Mixed sets usually work, sometimes even with full performance, but they always bring unnecessary risk.

Check whole part numbers, as memory can change pretty important details without changing the name (i.e. type of memory used).